# Python if statement with selenium: is there any way to shorten?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a selenium script that searches for any visible elements, prints if they are displayed or not and then appends them to a list (ButtonDisplayed or ButtonNotDisplayed). However this is very repetitive as I have to create an if else statement for every single element I check. Is there a way for me to shorten this code?

```
    if login.is_displayed():
        logInButtonDisplayed = "Login is displayed"
        print(logInButtonDisplayed)
        buttonDisplayed.append(logInButtonDisplayed)
    else:
        logInButtonNotDisplayed = "Login is not displayed"
        print(logInButtonNotDisplayed)
        buttonNotDisplayed.append(logInButtonNotDisplayed)

    if login.is_enabled():
        logInButtonEnabled = "Log In button is enabled"
        print(logInButtonEnabled)
        buttonEnabled.append(logInButtonEnabled)
    else:
        logInButtonDisabled = "Log In button is disabled"
        print(logInButtonDisabled)
        buttonDisabled.append(logInButtonDisabled)
```

Comment: Yes: write a function, parameterise it.

Comment: Hint: `f"Login is {'not ' if login.is_displayed() else ''}displayed"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using f-strings and conditional expressions.

```
def check_element_status(element, displayed_list, not_displayed_list, enabled_list, disabled_list):
    display_status = "displayed" if element.is_displayed() else "not displayed"
    enabled_status = "enabled" if element.is_enabled() else "disabled"

    display_message = f"{element.get_attribute('id')} is {'' if element.is_displayed() else 'not '}displayed"
    enabled_message = f"{element.get_attribute('id')} is {'' if element.is_enabled() else 'not '}enabled"

    print(display_message)
    print(enabled_message)

    displayed_list.append(display_message)
    not_displayed_list.append(display_message) if not element.is_displayed() else None
    enabled_list.append(enabled_message)
    disabled_list.append(enabled_message) if not element.is_enabled() else None

# Assuming you have login element
check_element_status(login, buttonDisplayed, buttonNotDisplayed, buttonEnabled, buttonDisabled)
```